# Entity Framework - Add reference to child object without retrieving entire list of objects?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have parent object which has childs property which is itself an collection object.   ie. Parent.Childs I am exposing these EF object through WCF.  Said another way parent can have multiple children as in the case of Invoice(parent) and LineItems (childs).

Client side how do i reference a Child object and add it to the Childs collection without going through the service and getting the entire list of children and setting manually Parent.Childs.Add(child) for each child object that matches.

I would like to do something like Parent.Childs = new Childs(){ new Child{childId=1}, new Child{childId=2}}; and then when i send Parent to server the server knows that a children with id=1 and id=2 already exists and hooks it up.  I am sure there is away.

I was reading about EntityKey property but my objects client side do not have this property at all.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var child1 = new Child{ childId = 1 };
    context.Children.Attach(child1);
    var parent = new Parent();
    parent.Children.Add(child1);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I am working through a wcf service with entity objects and so client side there isn't any such thing as 'context'

Comment: I use to try this solution and keep getting a "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key" I dunno how I should solve this... Any idea?

Comment: @SimonDugré, that's a duplicate key error. You need to update the object you've already loaded instead of trying to add a new object with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Server doesn't know if entity exists until it loads it from database. So when you add childs on client and send them to the server you also have to include information about new childs, updated childs and deleted childs. If you do not include such information you have to load complete entity graph from DB first and then compare received graph with loaded graph and process changes manually.

Automatic solution for such case can be Self tracking entities (STEs) but still your example will not work. STEs require you to load objects, send them to client, modify them and send them back. STEs will track all changes.

Comment: I am using STE's and currently I have to get all children from the server then client side add them i.e. parent.children.add(child) (where child is one that i received from the server).  It sounds like this is the only way to do this with STE's (is this correct?)

I wanted to just parent.children.add(new child(childid=1)) would work as when it goes to save to the db it would see that there is already a child with an id of 1 and not create a new one.